# "Build Failed" when trying to test Xamarin project, but build is successful when manually building

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a very simple Xamarin.Android project, last night I shut my machine off and today I came back to not being able to run my code:

When trying to run the project:

`Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.`

Yet I have no errors, and when I rebuild solution:

`1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App1, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  App1 -> C:\Users\Doug\source\repos\App1\App1\bin\Release\App1.dll
1>CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-multidex.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Any ideas? It probably has something to do with that multidex warning, but I'm not even using multi-dex so....

Comment: Check your emulators to make sure they didn't disappear. If it worked before, they might not be there anymore.

Comment: Can you include a full [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) to your question? Use a service like gist to host it.

Comment: My "go to solution" when I am dealing with build problems in Xamarin is to clean the solution, exit visual studio, delete the obj and bin folders, then start Visual Studio again and rebuild. Nine times out of ten it fixes the issue.

Comment: did you get any solutions?